# facing issues while adding lg-rotate class to my lightbox gallery in my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've implemented light gallery feature in my HTML file using the following version of jquery lightgallery.
http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/

I want to add rotate functionality on images in addition to the previous facilitated features. If using click action event for the rotation of the original pictures results in no change while opened using light box.

Is there any other way of rotating the picture using the same Jquery light box plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Reading on github, there already is an open issue with feature request for image rotation

https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/issues/245

So actually there isn't a way to rotate using this plugin, if you want an help for manual rotation please post your running code with jsfiddle, or wait for feature implementation.